# Error saying my global struct is uninitialized

Tags: c

```
static struct Hello {
   size_t h;
};
static Hello what;
```

At the top of my file I have a global struct initialized.

When I use Hello however, I get

"‘Hello’ undeclared (first use in this function)" and also

"expected expression before ‘)’ token" as errors.

Those errors are from:

```
*(Hello*)start = what;
```

what is going on?

Comment: There is no `Hello`. There is only `struct Hello`. Unless this is running out of a C++ compiler even the first snippet is fantasy code that can't possibly compile. Related,  the keyword `static` in the `static struct Hello` line is pointless, and ignored.

Comment: The first `static` does nothing (and is arguably an error)

Comment: `*(Hello*)start = what;` is dubious

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
typedef struct Hello
{
  size_t h;
} Hello;

static Hello what;
...
Hello *start;
start = &what;
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained what you changed and why.  You shouldn't rely on the comment(s) to the question to do the explaining.